# Calender is hiding , only background css is working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use *calendar* which I found on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/bBFgK).

But if I copy the code, I get only a blank page and only Background colour is changing to that which is in the styles nothing else.

I put that what I copied to [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHkTf/) and by [Codepen](http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/bBFgK) you will find the original

```
 <div id="datepicker" class="calendar"></div>
```

That's the html tag that I have in my `<Body>`, nothing else.

Comment: You need to include jQuery and jQuery UI references in your fiddle

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zHkTf/4/

Comment: Thanks, it works. Should take a break after hours of working. my mistake guys.

Comment: What i would like to know is, is it possible to Change the language of the month ? now is it english, i would like to Change it in german ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't added JQUERY in your fiddle
Add `Jquery.1.8.3`
and

Css Like

```
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -145px 0px 0px -140px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#datepicker div{
    width:420px;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zHkTf/10/)

Edit :

To make date picker in german language add this code

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ firstDay: 1});
```

[Localise to german](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603233/jquery-datepicker-localization-german)

[Demo of Date Picker in German](http://jsfiddle.net/73SsQ/121/)

Comment: I had edited my answer to make datepicker german and please See link of Localise to german too.

Comment: If its works for you then please watt up answer so that it will helps more to other to consider it as right answer and welcome