# How can I localize jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, datepicker, localization

I used jquery for a datepicker, which works fine. For the workout I used local files from jquery, which I localized for German Output (Mittwoch vs Wednesday, Mai vs May...)
All fine. Than I'd like to also use a autocomplete.
Also fine from jquery, but I had to  include an online version of jquery, which somehow overides the local settings. Eversgthing works fine, but the datepicker is English again. Can I localize the script or is there a Ger version?
Thanks
tsunami
Some: Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
      <title>www.olivereikel.de - Rem-O Reminder Online</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../mainimages/remo_favicon.ico">


                                                                               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../maincss/styles.css" media="screen and (min-width: 981px)"/>

<!-- Attribut "Print" f�r die PCausgabe -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../maincss/styles_mobil.css" media="screen and (max-width: 980px)"/>


<!-- <link href="../maincss/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
<link href="../maincss/hamburger.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--<link href="../maincss/alphacube.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="../maincss/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../maincss/manual.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   -->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>

<!--<link href="css/patches/patch_my_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />              -->

<![endif]-->
 <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

function wirklichloeschen(formname,quittung) {
    var antwort = confirm("Achtung! Mit dem Klick auf OK wird der Eintrag '"+quittung+"' endg&uuml;ltig aus der Datenbank gel&ouml;scht! Sind Sie sicher?")
    if (antwort==true){
        document.formname.submit(); 
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
 </script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
$$('input.DatePicker').each( function(el){
new DatePicker(el);
});
});
</script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>

function kategorie_waehlen()
{
document.kategorie_senden.submit();

}
</script> 
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
    function filtern(){
        document.filter_senden.submit();
        }
</script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
function kategorie_senden()
{
document.katabschicken.submit();
}
</script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
function vonoderan_senden()
{
document.katabschicken.submit();
}
</script>  
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function MM_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=="Netscape")&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; }}
else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH) location.reload();
}
MM_reloadPage(true);
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { 
window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
</script>

<!--********************tooltip********-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    wmtt = null;
    document.onmousemove = updateWMTT;
    function updateWMTT(e) {
    if (wmtt != null && wmtt.style.display == 'block') {
    var l = screen.availWidth - 550;
    var t = 20;
    wmtt.style.left =  l + 'px';
    wmtt.style.top = t + 'px';
    }
    }
    function showWMTT(id) {
    wmtt = document.getElementById(id);
    wmtt.style.display = "block";
    }
    function hideWMTT() {
    wmtt.style.display = "none";
    }
    -->
    </script>
     <!--   //******editor mit formatierung*************
 OF COURSE YOU NEED TO ADAPT NEXT LINE TO YOUR tiny_mce.js PATH -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
tinyMCE.init({
       mode : "exact",
             language : "de",
       elements : "nachrichtentextfeld"
        //theme : "simple"   //(n.b. no trailing comma, this will be critical as you experiment later)
});
</script >
<!-- //----------- Autologout------>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var sek = 600;
var timer;
function reset() 
{   
sek=600;
}
function countdown()
{
var restzeit = Math.round(sek/60);
sek--;          
document.getElementById('restlaufzeit').innerHTML=restzeit;     
document.getElementById('zaehler').style.width = sek/5 + 'px';
if(sek > 0){
timer = setTimeout('countdown()',1000);
}
else{
location.href='logout.php'; 
}  
}
</script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="datepicker/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="./datepicker/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="./datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
Alterdatepicker
-->
 <!-- Neuer Datepicker -->


<script src="./js/jquerymini.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquerymini2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../maincss/jquerycss.css"  type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="./js/jquery-datepicker-de.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../maincss/datepicker.css">  


</head>
<body onload="countdown();init();" onmousemove="reset()" onkeydown="reset();" lang="de-DE"><a name="oben"></a>
<div id="page_margins">
<div class="headertimo">
<div class="headerlinks"><img src="../mainimages/remo_logo.png" alt="" class="toplogo" border="none"/>

</div>

<div class='loginkasten'><div class='logintxt'><div class='firmenname'>lizensiert f&uuml;r: <strong>Angela Merkel Krankenhaus</strong><br/> </div>Eingelogged: <strong>Herr&nbsp;Oliver&nbsp;Eikel
                        </strong> als <strong>'oleikel'</strong>.  
                        <br/>Berechtigung: <strong>Administrator</strong>.<form method='POST' action='logout.php'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='x' value='abmelden'><input type='submit' name='' value='abmelden'></form><br/>
                    </div><br/>    
                    <div class='zeitlogoutbox'>&nbsp;Nach <span id='restlaufzeit' style='width:auto;'>  </span> Minuten Unt&auml;tigkeit werden Sie automatisch ausgeloggt.&nbsp;<div style='border: 1px solid black; width:121px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;float:left;'><div id='zaehler' style='height: 10px; width: 100px;  background: #003399; '></div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div></div>

<div class="time">
25.07.2017</div><!-- <script>
function weiterleitung(wohin) {
setTimeout("location.href='"+wohin+"';",1000);
}
</script> -->

   <h2 class='ueberschrift'>Neue Erinnerung</h2>
   </h2> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {$("#datepicker").datepicker();});
</script>    
<!-- ************* autotext -->
     <style>
     .ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }
     ul{list-style: none;
     border:1px solid grey;width:200px;
     }    input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
              opacity: 0;
           }
     </style>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
 <script>
         $(function () {
              $("#rowxxx").prop("disabled", true);
             var projects = [{value: "31",label:"1&1 Internet AG  - Telgte"},{value: "55",label:"Abdel Ghani Emad - Telgte"},{value: "53",label:"Ahmann Jürgen - Telgte"},{value: "44",label:"Ahmann Walter - Telgte"},{value: "107",label:"Ahmann Bianca - Telgte"},{value: "42",label:"Albrecht Sabrina - Telgte"},{value: "3",label:"Amazon.de  - Telgte"},{value: "14",label:"Bäuerle Beate - Telgte"},{value: "89",label:"Benning Charlotte - Telgte"},{value: "78",label:"Berger Karl-Heinz - Telgte"},{value: "58",label:"Borggreve Alfred - Telgte"},{value: "108",label:"Borggreve Marco - Telgte"},{value: "13",label:"buch.de internetstores AG  - Telgte"},{value: "91",label:"Buchmayr Karl-Heinz - Telgte"},{value: "7",label:"computeruniverse.net GmbH  - Telgte"},{value: "95",label:"Cremann Jochen - Telgte"},{value: "76",label:"Dahmen Norbert - Telgte"},{value: "65",label:"Demmer Heinz - Telgte"},{value: "9",label:"Deutsche Post AG  - Telgte"},{value: "39",label:"Diekmannshemke Günter - Telgte"},{value: "17",label:"Diekmannshemke Günther - Telgte"},{value: "59",label:"Dierkes Detlev - Telgte"},{value: "2",label:"Domainfactory GmbH  - Telgte"},{value: "60",label:"Dorgeist Theodor - Telgte"},{value: "18",label:"EDV & Büroservice Heuer GmbH  - Telgte"},{value: "23",label:"Eikel Ludger - Telgte"},{value: "87",label:"Ernst Friedrich - Telgte"},{value: "26",label:"Füchtenghans August - Telgte"},{value: "47",label:"Fechner Jörg - Telgte"},{value: "93",label:"Fellenberg Peter - Telgte"},{value: "111",label:"Fichert Iris - Telgte"},{value: "66",label:"Finanzamt Warendorf  - Telgte"},{value: "64",label:"Flotmann Martin - Telgte"},{value: "85",label:"Grothaus Georg - Telgte"},{value: "12",label:"Grunden Thomas - Telgte"},{value: "86",label:"Hahn Wolfgang - Telgte"},{value: "51",label:"Harsch Martin - Telgte"},{value: "79",label:"Heitmann Rolf - Telgte"},{value: "75",label:"Holzmüller Frank - Telgte"},{value: "80",label:"Jeschke Peter - Telgte"},{value: "105",label:"Johnson Roy - Telgte"},{value: "40",label:"Kühn Mathias - Telgte"},{value: "81",label:"Kammer Reinhard - Telgte"},{value: "97",label:"Kamphans Wolfgang - Telgte"},{value: "32",label:"KFW Bank  - Telgte"},{value: "1",label:"Kirchner Sven - Telgte"},{value: "37",label:"Kirchner Sven - Telgte"},{value: "102",label:"Kirchner Karin - Telgte"},{value: "52",label:"Kleideiter Michael - Telgte"},{value: "90",label:"Kloppenborg Ralf - Telgte"},{value: "83",label:"Klosterkamp Markus - Telgte"},{value: "54",label:"Kluge Oliver - Telgte"},{value: "57",label:"Koebbert Hans-Otto - Telgte"},{value: "38",label:"Kretschmmar GmbH  - Telgte"},{value: "72",label:"Kretzer Franz-Josef - Telgte"},{value: "99",label:"Landwehr Martin - Telgte"},{value: "10",label:"Lepper Roland - Telgte"},{value: "20",label:"Möhlmann Ralf - Telgte"},{value: "100",label:"Möllers Melanie - Telgte"},{value: "69",label:"Meyers Michael - Telgte"},{value: "110",label:"Neue Benedikt - Telgte"},{value: "6",label:"Poster XXL AG  - Telgte"},{value: "70",label:"Prinz Karuna - Telgte"},{value: "96",label:"Puga Josef - Telgte"},{value: "48",label:"Rösmann Bernd-Rainer - Telgte"},{value: "25",label:"Rüter Ludger - Telgte"},{value: "36",label:"Rickert Günther - Telgte"},{value: "33",label:"Rodenkirchen Bernhard - Telgte"},{value: "49",label:"Rutsch Heidrun - Telgte"},{value: "84",label:"Salger Klaus - Telgte"},{value: "94",label:"Schäfer Jutta - Telgte"},{value: "16",label:"Schabhüser Martin - Telgte"},{value: "45",label:"Schneider Norbert - Telgte"},{value: "68",label:"Schulze Helmut - Telgte"},{value: "50",label:"Schulze Helmut - Telgte"},{value: "82",label:"Schulze Zumkley Renate - Telgte"},{value: "74",label:"Schwering Herbert - Telgte"},{value: "71",label:"Spenst Julia - Telgte"},{value: "103",label:"Stein Herbert - Telgte"},{value: "88",label:"Stuppe Ludwig - Telgte"},{value: "104",label:"Thaele-Boehnke Doris - Telgte"},{value: "101",label:"Thoholte Hubertus - Telgte"},{value: "56",label:"Tomasello Camelo - Telgte"},{value: "5",label:"van de Vint Ian - Telgte"},{value: "24",label:"van Dijk Gustaaf Christiaan - Telgte"},{value: "67",label:"Vartmann Michael - Telgte"},{value: "98",label:"Vogelpohl Sylvia - Telgte"},{value: "106",label:"Vogelsang Adolf - Telgte"},{value: "61",label:"Wegener Stefanie - Telgte"},{value: "92",label:"Weidig Peter - Telgte"},{value: "77",label:"Wessels Beate - Telgte"},{value: "43",label:"Wortmann Franjo - Telgte"},{value: "11",label:"Yello Strom GmbH  - Telgte"},{value: "73",label:"Züwerink André - Telgte"},{value: "63",label:"Zeisberger Julia - Telgte"},{value: "34",label:"Zschoke Caroline - Telgte"}];
            $("#empfaenger").autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
                source: projects,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#empfaenger").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#empfaenger").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#empfaenger_id").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#rowxxx").prop("disabled", false);
                    return false;
                },
                selectFirst: true,
                click: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item == null) {
                        //here is null if entered value is not match in suggestion list
                        $(this).val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : ""));
                        //                 $( "#empfaenger_id" ).val( ui.item.value )="";
                        //               $( "#empfaenger" ).val( ui.item.value )="";
                        document.getElementById('rowxxx').disabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                        document.getElementById('rowxxx').disabled = false;
                }
            })
            $("#empfaenger").autocomplete("instance")._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
                var that = this;
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                });
                inp = $("#empfaenger");
                if (inp.val() == "") {
                    $("#rowxxx").prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    var found = false;
                    $.each(items, function (idx, item) {
                        if (item.label == inp.val()) {
                            found = true;
                            return false;
                        } else return true;
                    });
                    if (found) $("#rowxxx").prop("disabled", false);
                    else $("#rowxxx").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            };
        }); // dies fehlte
    </script>
```

The two lines:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

are the problem. Without the datepickers works fine in German, but autocomplete doens't work at all. With it, both scripts are working, but the datepicker in English...
any idea?
tsunami

Comment: Have you seen this answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: You should have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603233/jquery-datepicker-localization-german

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I localize the jQuery UI Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

thanks, this solved it:
[How do I localize the jQuery UI Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494958/how-do-i-localize-the-jquery-ui-datepicker/2905411#2905411)
In addition to the ger Version I had to define some Vars like Mon, Sat and Sun...
No it works!
tsunami