# Datepicker jQuery on Apache Webserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache

I want to change jQuery Datepicker to German Calendar, but it did not work.

-I tried that :

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "de" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).on( "change", function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below post,
You need to do mentioned modifications in the below post

[JQuery Datepicker Localization German](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603233/jquery-datepicker-localization-german)